# Pandas fillna row wise?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

It'a simple example.

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,None,None,3,4],'y':[3,2,3,None,7],'z':[None,None,None,None,None]})
d['t']=d.mean(axis=1)

Out[96]: 
     x    y     z    t
0  1.0  3.0  None  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  None  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  None  3.0
3  3.0  NaN  None  3.0
4  4.0  7.0  None  5.5
```

I want to fill NA with the mean of the row.The mean of every row I have added
as `t`.The result I want is:

```
x y z 
1 3 2
2 2 2
3 3 3
3 3 3
4 7 5.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
d.T.fillna(d.T.mean(axis=0), axis=0).T
```

You have to transpose the dataframe because this:

```
d.fillna(d.mean(axis=1), axis=1)
```

is not implemented (NotImplementedError)

Comment: It's a good solution. But I'm wondering if there is more direct and simple method. I think the developers of pandas should have met the same problem.